# После переноса папки проекта перестали компилироваться новые изменения в коде

Tags: android, android-studio

После переноса папки проекта на другое место перестали компилироваться любые новые изменения в коде.

Генерю специально ошибку - компилятор реагирует и не дает скомпилировать проект, однако в случае если ошибок нет, но внесены изменения в код - компилируется старая версия (как до переноса). Не открываются из Android Studio папки java/assets... Rebuild/clean делал...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохрани проект на другой диск,  удали существующий из списка и импортируй заново.

Answer (score 1):

Удалить проект из android studio, затем выбрать **File -> Invalidate cashes/restart** , открыть заново проект

Comment: Не помогло. При сохранении, кстати, и последующем открытии проекта - изменения в коде есть, а компилируется старая версия.....

Comment: @Chekist, в чем отличия "старой" и "новой" версии?

Comment: Имеется ввиду - изменения в самом коде сохраняются и загружаются когда заново открываю проект, а компилируется версия кода "до этих изменений".

Comment: @Chekist, честно говоря, я не понимаю, как такое бывает вообще